# Linking background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

```
#logo {
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);

}
```

I can't seem to link my logo image in my background-image tag and it's killing me. The image is a usual .png img that has been saved in my images folder.

Below is my folder path.The logo is 85 x 85 hence the div dimensions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you missed `../` in url If you are writing you styling in css folder

```
#logo {
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    background-image: url(../images/logo.png);

}
```

I hope this will solve your issue

Comment: such an easy answer !